# After merge pull request accepted, can I revoke it?

Tags: github, git-merge, pull-request

Sometimes, I accept my developers pull request and merge it, after that, I find that, the task is not properly works. That time, how can I revoke this?

Comment: Not strictly speaking, no. You could however revert the merge commit for the pull request (I find this to be the cleanest option -- if you go back to the pull request there should be a revert option for the commit where the PR was merged), or manually revert all the commits contained in the pull request, or go scorched earth and rebase to the commit before the merge.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.